# How do you pronounce "one of" quicky?

Tags: pronunciation

I usually pronounce it as "wanov" but not sure if it's the correct pronounction and need some clarification.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More **wun-ov** than **on-ov**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Americans are very likely to drop the **v** sound if the next word begins with a consonant. The result is more like **wunnuh**.

If the next word begins with a vowel, as in "one of a kind", I don't think we're as likely to drop the **v**. So the result is more like **wunnuv**.

Comment: I think this depends on the following sound and whether it's a vowel or not.  If the following sound is a consonant, as in "one of these", we  drop the v sound, but if it's a vowel, as in "one of a kind", I don't think we're as likely to.

Answer (score 3):

"wun-uv" or "wun-nuh" depending on the dialect.

Comment: What about 'wun-ov'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Of is normally pronounced with a schwa vowel, at least in my (American) dialect. I find it hard to believe that someone speaking quickly would un-reduce the schwa to some other vowel.